# Jython script to modify queue connection factories

Tags: websphere, jython

I have queue manager already configured in Queue connection factories of websphere
currently settings are with out SSl enabled.

I want to enable this two things

- Use SSL to secure communication with IBM MQ
- specify the SSl to be used

Need your help to edit this things through jython

Answer (score 0):

Use [modifyWMQConnectionFactory](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=scripting-modifywmqconnectionfactory-command) command for this task.

See below example:

```
#Set QCF Name
qcfName='MYQCF'

#Set custom SSL config name
sslConfig='CUSTOMSSLSettings'

#Get the list of all QCF's in the environment
qcfList=AdminConfig.list('MQQueueConnectionFactory').splitlines()

#You can futher refine this command and restrict the query to a specific resource scope 
#eg: qcfList=AdminConfig.list('MQQueueConnectionFactory', clusterId).splitlines()

#Iterate the list and update the config for MYQCF
for qcf in qcfList:
    if qcfName == AdminConfig.showAttribute(qcf, 'name'):
        print 'Enable SSL config for QCF: '+qcfName+' and use '+sslConfig+' SSL configuration'
        AdminTask.modifyWMQConnectionFactory(qcf, '[-sslType SPECIFIC -sslConfiguration '+sslConfig+']')
    else:
        print 'Skip SSL config update for QCF: '+AdminConfig.showAttribute(qcf, 'name')

#save the changes
AdminConfig.save()
```